# Div with a simple variable height

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, height

So, I want to make a div that has the height of a value I'm going to get from my database. To make it better do understand, the value is a the number of times a client has bought in the website. I'm thinking of a way to make my div go up as the value go up.

Something like this:

```
var divHeight = numberOfValues;
numberOfValues = heightOfDiv; (div's height property)

if (numberOfValues == 0) {
   divHeight = 0;
} else {
    divHeight = numberOfValues + 10;
}
```

The logic is to have my div increase in 10px for every value number. So if the value is 10 the height should be 100px.

What is the best way for me to achieve this solution? Is it as simple as I think? (Simple != easy).

Comment: for starters, you will want numberOfValues * 10, not +10 :)

Comment: Do you need this to happen without a page refresh?

Comment: Not really, I don't want the solution on the animation side of things, I just want the height to change based on the value.

Comment: Do you know how to get value from the database with ajax?

Comment: That's actually something I have no idea how to do. How can I get the value from the database and put it into that variable? Or how can I use it in my JS logic?

Comment: If you know how to get the value from the database in PHP, my answer below shows how you can use this in your Javascript. Does that help?

Comment: Ok, do you work with PHP&MySQL, can you write a php/sql script that will get a value from the database? If you can do that then I could help you with jQuery/Ajax of course if you are familiar with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$numberOfPurchases = getNumberOfPurchases(); // call the function that queries the database
?>
<script>
var defaultDivHeight = 10;
var purchaseDiv = document.getElementById('purchaseDiv');
if (<?= numberOfPurchases; ?> > 0)
{
    purchaseDiv.style.height = <?= numberOfPurchases; ?> * defaultDivHeight + 'px';
}
else
{
    purchaseDiv.style.height = defaultDivHeight + 'px';
}
</script>
```

I suggest looking into using PDO in PHP for querying the database.

Comment: I'll apply this once I'm done getting the value from the database, but I think that's about right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
       var divHeight = numOfVisits * 10;
       var divDisplay = document.getElementById("display");

       if(divHeight>0)
              divDisplay.style.height = divHeight + "px";
       else
              divDisplay.style.height = "1px";
    </script>
```

Comment: why have you surrounded Javascript with style tags?